# "bad input shape" for target set in logistic regression

Tags: python, arrays, logistic-regression

```
X_train shape = (187, 12432), 
y_train shape = (187, 5),
shape of y_train = 
[[1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]
 ...]
```

I'm getting the error "bad input shape" when trying to fit on a logistic regression classifier. Is it possible to use an array of arrays with the above-mentioned dimensionality as the y_train?

Comment: Did you one hot encode or label encode categorical data?

Comment: I have updated the description, the y_train example is now given, is it necessary to do one hot encoding for that?

Comment: your y data are not one-hots (only 1 value 1), not softmax outputs(sum values = 1), what r they?

Comment: there are 5 different categories, 1 and 0 are used to suggest whether that particular row belongs to which category. I took those columns from the DataFrame and assigned them to y.